# Gauss law in crystals, Madelung constant

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals

I have a question regarding the calculation of the Madelung constant in **ionic** crystals. One of the well known methods for the calculation is the expanding-neutral shells method.I understand why the summation should be done this way and the physical meaning behind it. But I dont understand how to choose those shells/cubes so that the charge inside them is 0, or how to prove that it is.

**I have a theory**:

Let's say I want to do a expanding-neutral-cubes summation to obtain the Madelung constant. I now take a cube that's centered at a lattice atom. On opposite sides of the cube the electric field vector ($\textbf E$) should point in the same direction, because of the crystal symmetry. But the area elements ($\textbf {dA}$) should point in opposite directions. Therefore the integrals $\int_S \textbf E \space  \textbf{dA}$ on opposite sides should cancel out. So $\int_{all\space opp. sides} \textbf E \textbf{ dA}=0 $ that is the integral over the whole cube. And since according to Gauss's law: $\int_{all\space opp. sides} \textbf E \textbf{ dA}=e_{inside}=0 $. Where the sphere should have a volume of at least $(2a)^3$, where a is the distance to the nearest neighbours of the atom at which the cube is centered at.

Is this the correct way of thinking?

Comment: One chooses polyhedra with neutral facets, but there will often be charges on the edges and on vertices. These  contribute less and less with larger cells, and should also be of alternating sign.

Comment: I don't understand... How does one choose the right polyhedra?

Comment: In the NaCl-structure, the polyhedra are cubes with 001 faces. I like the image on this page: https://numbers.carma.newcastle.edu.au/page/lvl3/45.html  The bottom one converges well, the one above that does not.